# Is it possible to add wildcards to @Query parameters?

Tags: jpa-2.0, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've defined my ContactDao as follows:

```
public interface ContactDao extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long> {

  /**
   * Finds all contacts that the given user has entered where the contact's full name matches {@code name}.
   * @param userId The current user's LDAP id.
   * @param name The name to search for.
   * @return A list of contacts matching the specified criteria.
   */
  @Query(" select c from Form as f" +
           " inner join f.contacts as c" +
           " where f.requestorUserId = :userId" +
           " and lower(c.fullName) like lower(:name)" +
           " order by lower(c.fullName)")
  List<Contact> findUserContactsByUserIdAndName(@Param("userId") String userId, @Param("name") String name);

}
```

The above is working perfectly, and the SQL generated is what I'd write myself. The problem is that I'd like to add surrounding wild-cards to the `:name` parameter. Is there any nice way to do this? I've had a look at the Spring Data JPA reference document and I can't find anything regarding wildards and `@query`.

The following hack works, but is a bit ugly:

```
and lower(c.fullName) like '%' || lower(:name) || '%'
```

Does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks,
Muel.

Comment: A slightly off-topic side-note in case any _Spring Data_ authors are about.. :) Perhaps this kind of feature (bounding with wildcards) could be added to `@Param`; eg `@Param(value="name", wildcardStategy=WildcardStrategy.BOTH)`. Admittedly, I've given this very little thought, so there are probably strong arguments against it!

Answer (score 3):

I would also not call it a hack - it's the way JPQL syntax is defined for exactly these problems.

However, there is an alternative using a [CriteriaBuilder/CriteriaQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#like%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29), but maybe you find it even more complex (but you get compile-time type safety in return).

Comment: Personally, I'm not a huge fan of the criteria API. I do find it more complex than JPQL, and less readible (though others will disagree with me here!). While it provides compile-time type-safety, it doesn't guarantee it will execute nicely at run-time. Especially when using Hibernate! The one time that I do find the Criteria API very useful is when creating custom queries based on user input (eg a search form). Thanks for the answer!